# Print an array the way it is written in code?

Tags: php, arrays, pretty-print

I'm generating localization files in Laravel that look something like this:

```
<?php
return [
  'hello' => 'world',
  'foo' => 'bar',
];
```

Just a normal array, nothing fancy. I'm looking for a way to do this, I've looked at the `serialize` method but it doesn't fit my needs. Is there a way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Also note that my array only consists of string keys and values. Since this is localization work, some strings are UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_export` works well for this, it will pretty-print your array a lot like the format you specified above

```
echo(var_export($array_variable, true));
```

Comment: Yep, this is the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your data as an JSON string with [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($metaDesc);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```